# Wireshark with lua

Tags: wireshark, centos

I have installed wireshark on my Centos Machine. 
I want an auto script for it and i am planning to script it using LUA.
However, my wireshark is without LUA. How to enable wireshark which allows LUA scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you installed Wireshark.  If you did it from source code directly, then just doing this before `make` should work:

```
./configure --with-lua
```

If you did it with an RPM then it depends on how the RPM gets/takes a flag to do so, or in its .spec file.